# BackboneJs- How to render html template from the view controller in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am looking to render a table from the view controller using the data in the list.html. below is my View.js file:

```
function($, _, Backbone, SubAccountCollection){
    var AccountList = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "div",
        el:'#sub-account-list', 
        initialize: function(){

        },
        render: function(id){
            console.log('inside the account list ' + id);
            var self = this;
            var accountList = new SubAccountCollection([],{ id: id });

            accountList.fetch({
                success: function(accnlist){
                    var template = _.template($('#listall').html({accnlist:accnlist.models}) 
                }
            );
        }

    });
    return AccountList;
});
```

The `sub-account-list` is the div container or a placeholder for my data. The `$('#listall')` has a `<table>` that list the view.
Below is the list.html:

```
<script type = "text/template" id ="listall">
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td>
        <td>Users</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(accountList, function(account) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= account.get('name') %></td>
                <td><%= account.get('users') %></td>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
      </table>
 </script>
```

So now obviously its not rendering anything and when i tried debugging, it gave an undefined on `$('#listall').html()`. when i try to access the `_.template($('#listall').html(), {accnlist:accnlist.models})`, it throws 'Cannot find replace of undefined', which means its not able to find the `$('#listall').html()`. How can i access the element, so that it does not throw this error. Waht im i doing wrong in getting the values form the DOM. 
I've been stuck on this for a while, anyone has any ideas?

EDIT:::::

```
var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($("#listall").html()),
        initialize: function(options){
           this.id = options.id;
           this.collection = new ProjectsCollection();
           this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);
           this.collection.fetch();
        },
        el: "#container",
       render: function(){

       var template = this.template({projectlists: this.collection.toJSON()});
        this.$el.html(template)
           }
     });
   var accountList = new AccountList({

  });
 return ProjectListView;
});
```

list.html

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td>
        <td>Users</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(accnlist, function(account,idx) { %>
             <tr>
                <td><%= account.name %></td>
                <td><%= account.users %></td>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
      </table>
```

Above is the code suggested by Ofer in the fiddle that i tried, but i have no clue why would it say "undefined" on $('#listall').html(). I'm totally missing something minor that im not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first _.template function, returns a function which accepts the model, you can avoid this by calling it once _.template("template",{model object})

```
        accountList.fetch({
            success: function(accnlist){
                var template = _.template($('#listall').html(), {accnlist:accnlist.toJSON()});
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Ofer Haber: I'm sorry, but i didnt quite get what you're trying to suggest here. Can you help me understand. Thanks!

Comment: Your call to the _.template function is constructed like this:
`_.template($('#listall').html({accnlist:accnlist.models})` 

A single parameter would cause _.template function to return another function, which in order to be compiled, should accept the model. for instace:

with 1 parameter:

`var listTemplate = _.template($('#listall').html());
var compiledList = listTemplate({accnlist:accnlist.toJSON()});`

You can avoid the two calls by doing this once: 
`var template = _.template($('#listall').html(), {accnlist:accnlist.toJSON()});`
Also refer to http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: ahh, i see now. Thanks for the explanation. However i do not see any luck. I still get 'null' on this: $('#listall').html(). and when i run var template = _.template($('#listall').html(), {accnlist:accnlist.toJSON()}); i get the same error: 'Cannot read property of null', any ideas what im doing wrong. I've also edited the changes i made to my code above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have created a mock in jsFiddle. Please look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbcpe/

Please note i have overriden "fetch" in order to provide a mock

Comment: Ofer: thanks, i think im getting the hang of it. above is the code i tred u suggested in fiddle, but still no luck..:( i know im missing something minor, but cant figure out. Please can you help???Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if there is something off with the structure im following. I'm following the http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/ mentioned in the website.

Comment: if i run from the 'index.html' that is at the same level where i have my main.js and router.js etc., i get the content inside my div on $('#listall').html(). I'm wondering how to access the content from the templates dir.

Comment: i figured what was happening with my code. my list.html was being overwritten by my main view that had the same selector id..:( i changed it and it worked. Thanks for all the suggestions..